# Cannot Include views in ReportModel for SSRS Adhoc Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a Report Model , so that I can create entities for adhoc reports using the Report Builder tool.

I create the datasource and the datasourceview first.

I see that my view is included in the datasource view but ,
 when I create a report model from the 
 datasourceview, I see only entities created out of tables .
 The view is missing from my report model.

Is there any way I can include a view in the report model ? I am using BIDS tool.